# button is not displaying in layout file android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/users"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayer"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New User"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to display a button in bottom of the activity. but above code doesn't show a button.

Can anyone help me what is wrong here?

Comment: where do you want to show your button actually, after all list items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will properly align your relative layout including Listview(above button) and button(parent bottom aligned) below toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLayer"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayer"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            >
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/users"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/button_add_new_user"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_add_new_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add New User"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your listview and button in a relativelayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayer"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/users"

        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayer"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New User"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

```
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayer">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Add New User" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayer">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayer"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_new_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New User"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```